# google recaptcha error in codeigniter php while submiting form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, controller, recaptcha

i have created a form in codeigniter and given a google captcha v2, i have created the site key and secret key added it to config files, and also added the js and the recaptcha div including my site key. the following is my captcha function in controller:

```html
public function validate_captcha() {
          $recaptcha = trim($this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response'));
          $userIp= $this->input->ip_address();
          $secret='xxxxxxxxxxxx'; (i have given my scret key here)
          $secretdata = array(
              'secret' => "$secret",
              'response' => "$recaptcha",
              'remoteip' =>"$userIp"
          );

          $verify = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
          curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
          curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($secretdata));
          curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          $response = curl_exec($verify);
          $status= json_decode($response, true);
          if(empty($status['success'])){
              return FALSE;
          }else{
              return TRUE;
          }
      }
```

the following is my register form function in same controller:

```html
public function ajaxRegAction() {
   $this->load->library('session');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $utype='W';
    $dhamu = $this->validate_captcha();
  $createddate  = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
  $createdby = '0';
  $mobile = $this->input->post('phone');
  $form_data = array(
    'type' => $utype,
    'unique_id' => $this->mainModel->generateIndividualID(),
    'phone_num' => $mobile,
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
    'last_name' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
    'created_by' => $createdby,
    'created_date' => $createddate,
  );
  $name = $this->input->post('firstname')." ".$this->input->post('lastname');
  $access_info = array('user_type'=>$utype);

   $check = $this->mainModel->checkUserAvail($this->input->post('phone'),$this->input->post('email'));
   $checkauser = $this->mainModel->checkAjaxUser($this->input->post('phone'),$this->input->post('email'));
   if($check==0) {

        if($dhamu==1){

    $insert = $this->mainModel->ajaxRegInsertUser($form_data, $access_info,$this->input->post('password'));

    $message="Dear ".$this->input->post('firstname').", You have successfully registered with Book The Party. Thank You for coming On-Board. Contact us at 9666888000 for any queries - Team BTP";
    $email_message=$message;
    $message=rawurlencode($message);
    $this->mainModel->sendOtptoCustomer($mobile,$message);
    $this->mainModel->sendmailtoCustomer($this->input->post('email'),$email_message);

echo "success";
}

else{ echo "Captcha Error";}



}

else{
echo "Registration Failed !";

   }
```

even if i check the google recaptcha box and press register, the form is showing  "Captcha Error", values are not being added to the database also. can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `$this->validate_captcha();` returns `true`?

Comment: because that is where you're getting the message from,`if($dhamu==1){` condition fails hence you get the error message

Comment: @sauhardnc now i tried echoing $dhamu and its not displaying any value

Comment: @sauhardnc what could be the reason the conditions is failing

Comment: which probably means its `false`, Now check `$status` if it has `success` in it.

Comment: which probably means its `false`, Now check `$status` if it has `success` in it.

Comment: @sauhardnc where should i echo it?

Comment: In your method `validate_captcha()` after `$status= json_decode($response, true);` do `print_r($status);`

Comment: @sauhardnc gave the statment there but nothing is printed above the form

Comment: use `die;` after `print_r($status);` to stop the control after this statement

Comment: @sauhardnc its printing "array"

Comment: so it means that it is empty and doesn't have any value hence it returns false, now you'll have to check the code above it and see where you messed up.

Comment: you mean the recaptcha function code?

Comment: @sauhardnc actually i have 2 subdomains, and for both subdomains i created separate captcha, and the same function code in the controller, the first subdomain is working fine, but the second one is having the above error

Comment: currently, I think something is wrong with the code above `$success` because as you can see it doesn't return true as desired.

Comment: @sauhardnc but the same code is working fine for another sub domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
Make sure you have added `localhost` in your domain in Google Captcha V2 dashboard.

Step 2:

I am modifying your function you can use it like this:

```
public function validate_captcha() 
{
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }

    $secretKey = "Put your secret key here";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // post request to server
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
    // should return JSON with success as true
    if($responseKeys["success"]) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

instead of CURL

Do let me know if this works

Comment: i added your step 2 code, but still its showing captcha error even when i tick the captcha

Comment: can you tell me how to add localhost